# jquery post запрос(json ответ)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Доброго всем дня. При клике на ссылку, пытаюсь получить из б.д. запись по id. Для запроса использую Jquery. В моём случае вижу только следующие ответы (Ответ получен/Пришли не те данные). Объясните на примере, какой формат json данных должен возвращать на запрос сервер. Сам код:

```
function test(par){

 var Rec = $.Deferred();
 var Rec = $.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST',
     url: "test.php",
     data: {'id' : par},
     dataType: "json"
 });

 $.when(Rec).done(function(res) { 
     alert('Ответ получен: ', res);

     if (res.success) {
        alert('ОК!)');
     } else { 
        alert('Пришли не те данные!');
     }
 });


$.when(Rec).fail(function() { 
  alert('Ошибка выполнения запроса!');
});
   }
```

HTML:

< a href="#" onclick="test('324')">test

Ответ от серва:

```
   echo '{"id" : "ответ", "name" : "ivan", "old" : "42"}';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '{"id" : "ответ", "name" : "ivan", "old" : "42", "success" : "true"}';
```

У функции `window.alert` только один параметр. Используйте:

```
console.log(res);
```

Сделайте вот так:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST',
  url: "test.php",
  data: {'id' : par},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("SUCCESS:");
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
    console.log(jqXHR);
  }
});
```

а `$.when(Rec)...` уберите. Что появляется в консоли?

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Comment: ERROR: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token = in JSON at position 26 <br/>      Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, stRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…} <br/>       В responseText прописана собственно сама JSON строка:<br/> "{"warnings":[], "success" => "true", "name" => "ivan", "old" => "42"}"

Comment: Всё понятно, у меня в JSON ответе были недопустимые символы. Вы не посоветуете как организовать запись ошибок?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов каких ошибок, запись куда?

Comment: Хотел просто уточнить, при ajax выбора, вообще ведут какой-либо журнал ошибок и в каких ситуациях. Может в б.д. или в log файлы.